# How do I make appending large vectors to list faster

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to implement skip gram algorithm in plain numpy (not pytorch) which requires doing calculation (possibly avoidable details at the end):

```
xy = []

for i in tqdm(range(100000)):
    for j in range(15):
        xy.append([np.zeros(50000), np.zeros(50000)])
```

So, this is a huge array `15*100000*2*50000` elements of type `numpy.float64`. There are two issues here:

1. This takes huge memory (at least 3 GBs) as explained above. In fact, I was never able to complete this calculation because of second issue mentioned below. But it easily filled all my laptop RAM (total  16 GB).
2. This takes huge time (at least couple of hours), may be because of first issue above.

I also tried to pre-generate x with all zeroes as follows:

```
 count = 15*100000
 xy = [[np.zeros(vocabSize), np.zeros(vocabSize)] for _ in range(count)]
```

But the moment I step over this second line in my debugger, my RAM fills up.

How can deal with this?

**Avoidable details**

I am trying to implement skip gram algorithm, in which we have to prepare list of skip grams `[target-word, context-words]`. Each target-word and context-words are represented as one hot vector of size equal to input vocabulary size (50000 above). 100000 above is number of sentences in data. 15 is average number of words per sentence.

**PS**

I have to implement this in plain python + numpy. That is not using any ML library like pytorch or tensorflow

Comment: Never represent one-hot vectors explicitly. You can use e.g. just the number `2` to represent a one-hot vector for the second index, i.e. `0 0 1 0 0 ...`. This cuts memory need by a factor of `vocab_size`.

Comment: How did you estimate 3 GB? It's 1.2 TB.

Comment: @KellyBundy I did not estimate, I just found that my machine starts freezing after filling up that much of memory... Also X and Y are one hot matrices. Will it help using scipy sparse matrices?

Comment: @xdurch0 never? **Q1.** Is that a standard practice in ML world? **Q2.** Also do you mean, just keep indices and when it is time to give input to model, generated one hot vector for that sample (or minibatch) (and dont pre compute all one hot vectors in advance)? **Q3.** Also X and Y are one hot matrices. Will it help using scipy sparse matrices?

Comment: Q1: Yes. Q2: Maybe, depends on the model. E.g. in Tensorflow I would implement skipgrams using an `Embedding` layer, which takes the indices directly. But if you _need_ one-hot vectors, then creating them only on a per-batch basis, instead of for the whole dataset, is the next best thing. Q3: Sparse matrices are basically the same thing as the index representation for one-hot vectors. You can use them, but sometimes they are incompatible with the operations you'd like to use.

Answer (score 0):

100000 sentences * 15 words per sentence * 50000 vocabulary size * 2 * 8 bytes per float 64 = 1200000000000 bytes = 1200 GiB. You cannot initialize this object in memory on your 16 GiB laptop.
My guess is that you do not want to store all of the vectors of every sentence in memory but instead run the algorithm sentence by sentence? In this case it would take 12 MiB of memory per sentence.

Comment: The X and Y are one hot matrix. Will it help using scipy sparse matrices?